# Refresh rate lag issue in Dashboard in Power-BI with Stream Analytics

Tags: stream, streaming, azure-stream-analytics

I am integrating a simulated service with a Raspberry that sends temperature signals to an Azure IOT-Hub service, where I process the events through Azure Stream Analytics and display them in a Dashboard in Power-BI. So far so good.

I have problems when deploying them in Power-BI. Shortly after the service starts, the Dashboard begins to have delays in the refresh rate. I would like to know why this happens?

Is it necessary to have a larger Stream cluster?
Is Power-BI an issue with refresh rate?
It can be fixed?

From already thank you very much.

Regards

Comment: Could you please give us an estimate of how much data you're sending Power BI? Also do you see any watermark delay at the ASA job level?

Comment: The simulator sends the temperature sensor to the azure service every 2 seconds. I don't know the watermark settings, what is it for?